# HTML Spreadsheet fixed headers and leftmost column

Tags: html, css, tabular

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet similar to Google Docs Spreadsheet or Excel where you have a table full of data.  How do I make it so when I scroll vertically, the first row stays fixed and when the user scrolls horizontally, the first column stays fixed?  I'm not looking for a plugin, just how is this done using HTML/CSS?  I've been looking at the code for Google Docs Spreadsheet, but I'm unable to pinpoint the solution.  Can someone provide a simple example for this?

For example:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tYUwd/2/

In the jsFiddle, when you scroll horizontally, I'd like `.row-header` elements to be fixed.  When you scroll vertically, `.column-headers` are to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain this cannot currently be done with only HTML/CSS. You can do a fixed header or a pseudo fixed first column with just HTMl/CSS, but you need JavaScript to get both working together. I would suggest checking out this site: http://www.8164.org/the-big-table-issue/

I would also suggest checking out these two possible solutions:
http://cross-browser.com/x/examples/xtable.php
http://www.disconova.com/open_source/files/freezepanes.htm

I've used the Freeze Panes solution before and it works great.